# Non-normal random effects in a logistic GAM

Tags: logistic, random-effects-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have estimated the following GAM using the `mgcv` package:

```
sex ~ factor + s(x0, by = factor, bs = "ps", k = 20) + 
    s(x1, bs = "ps", k = 20) + s(x2, bs = "ps", 
    k = 20) + s(x3, bs = "ps", k = 20) + s(x4, bs = "ps", 
    k = 20) + s(x5, bs = "ps", k = 20) + s(x6, bs = "ps", 
    k = 20) + s(mun, bs = "re") + s(region, bs = "mrf", 
    xt = xt)
```

However, when plotting the results, the random effect does not seem to follow a Gaussian distribution.

[image]

Is there a way to correct that to improve the model?

Comment: What information, coming out of the model, are you hoping to improve?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I was thinking if I should do a transformation in the covariates or any other measure that make the random effect fit the Gaussian quantiles.

Comment: @whuber: I am guessing he would like the distribution of the random effects for municipalities (mun) to look closer to normal? 

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks Isabella

Comment: I met this situation in my real job, and did not find the solution. I tried to specify the random effect as other distribution, but the MLE is unmanageable.

Comment: This article - albeit about GLMMs not GAMMs - may come in handy: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.1980.pdf.

Comment: For more reading, see also: https://niasra.uow.edu.au/content/groups/public/@web/@inf/@math/documents/mm/uow236296.pdf.

Comment: I think it's going to be tough to implement non-Gaussian random effects.  See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45656714/user-defined-random-intercept-distribution-for-glmer) or the `spaMM` package; combining these with penalized regression approaches could be tricky ...

Comment: What's not clear to me is *why* you want the distribution to be closer to normality? As I elaborate below, if this is related to the test for the random effect spline in the output from `summary()`, then Wood's (2013) test seems robust to departures from normality of the $b_j$, and otherwise, we might not worry about traditional random effect theory here as this is estimated as a penalized spline with a ridge penalty, and is, sensu Hodges (2016), a *new-style random effect*, and is just a convenient way to compute the thing we want to compute, but perhaps not do inference on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not want or need to worry about the departure from the normality assumption. Wood (2013) shows (in the Supplementary Materials, and mentioned in the text) that the test of the random effect term (as shown/performed in a call of `summary()` on the estimated GAM) is quite robust to failures of the normality assumption for the random effects.

So, if you are wanting to improve the distribution of the random effects to better meet the assumptions of the test of the variance component, you may not need to, except at quite small sample sizes (Simon mentions some loss of power at a sample size of 100, for example).

Should you (we) even care about the distribution? If you are just including this in the model to account for clustering in the data, perhaps we could simply appeal to Hodges (2016) and consider the penalized spline version of random effects as a convenient computational trick to estimate the things we want to estimate?

References:

- Hodges, J. S. 2016. Richly Parameterized Linear Models: Additive, Time Series, and Spatial Models Using Random Effects, CRC Press.
- Wood, S. N. 2013. A simple test for random effects in regression models. Biometrika 100: 1005–1010. doi:[10.1093/biomet/ast038](https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/ast038)